# How to stop grub menu from coming up everytime

Tags: multi-boot

I'm on a thinkpad x220, dual booting windows 7 and ubuntu 16.04. When I close my laptop or even hibernate, the next time I open my laptop, it boots into the grub menu. I have a ssd and it is sorta fast, but this still takes a lot more time. Is there something I am doing wrong, or something I can do so that windows 7 loads up without booting into grub to make this faster? Thanks!

Comment: Changing the order of the boot loaders isn't for the inexperienced, if you do it incorrectly, the end result is a system that cannot boot to either operating system.  Changing your configuration so the Windows Bootloader is used first, then an option to boot into grub, is the solution to your problem though.  If you have never changed the order I suggest, NOT attempting to do this, and living with the slowness.

Comment: Right now when i go to hardware and sound -> power options -> system settings(on windows 7), under *when i close the lid*, sleep is set for both on battery and plugged in. I don't think hibernation is a problem, I have a 16gb swap. What else can I try? Should I select *hibernate* instead?

Comment: Your problem cannot be solved from within Windows..

Comment: The computer powers down in hibernation but not in sleep mode.  If sleep mode is working correctly, you should not see any bootloader when you open the lid or restart it; it should just resume.  Sounds like sleep mode is not working correctly, unless you are leaving it in sleep so long that it runs the battery down.

Comment: okay, well thanks for the comment. I'll definitely stay away from changing the boot orders as it isn't a huge deal, but would be nice if hibernation worked properly.

Comment: Maybe sleep mode isn't working properly then? Also, should I try going to the start menu and selecting sleep? Right now, I just simply close the lid.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to try selecting sleep from the start menu, just to narrow down what might not be working right.  But if you have lid closure set for sleep, that's what it should do if it's working correctly.

Comment: selecting sleep from the start menu worked
! now to find the keyboard shortcut

Comment: Consider posting an answer.  That will help future readers who encounter the same problem.  Glad you at least found a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is lower the grub timeout. Sounds like it might be set at a higher value than comfortable. Is Windows already set as the default OS?

1. Open linux command line
2. From the linux command line you're going to want to edit `/etc/default/grub` with `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
3. Look for a line similar to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`
4. Set this number to 2 or 3. What this is doing is changing how long the menu is up. It would take more focus when changing operating systems due to the reduced amount of time.
5. Once the change has been completed `ctrl+x` would cause nano to ask if the changes are right press `y` when satisfied.
6. Update grub to take in the new changes with `sudo update-grub`
7. Done